# ffmpeg for android guardian project build failing

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I am a noob and i am trying to compile a static build of ffmpeg for android using "**guardian project**" repo. (https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg)

I have followed the steps mentioned in there, but it fail all the time. I am using Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit using vmware. Android NDk r8e 32 bit.

Here is the complete log of android-ffmpeg compilation. http://bit.ly/1mgZqeV

Also have a look at the terminal command window showing the errors......

It seems that make files are not done.

[image: compile time terminal view]

Please help me if some one has more clear understanding.